# IntelliJ IDEA, maven project does not automatically import dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I imported a maven project, but idea does not automatically import dependencies.

But I've checked the box for "Import Maven projects automatically".

I tried to delete .idea  and .iml and re-import the project.

About idea:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-181.4445.78, built on April 10, 2018
Licensed to **
Subscription is active until October 14, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b27 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.4
```

The structure of my project in idea：
[image]

Update problem！

I found something wrong with my *pom.xml*,If I change into other *pom.xml*, I can import the dependency automatically. But I don't know where the problem is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.dai</groupId>
    <artifactId>micro</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring-boot.version>2.0.2.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.1</commons-lang3.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.4.1212</postgresql.version>
        <commons-codec.version>1.10</commons-codec.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.2</httpclient.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <java-jwt.version>3.2.0</java-jwt.version>
        <wsdl4j.version>1.6.3</wsdl4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
                <version>${java-jwt.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
                <classifier/>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
                <version>${wsdl4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>xjc</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>xjc</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build> </project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `packaging` define is `pom`, and you have just `dependencyManagement` not `dependency` section. These defines is used for parent pom. You may check [maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for information about them.

To solve:

Change `packaging` to `jar` and remove the `dependencyManagement` while keep the `dependency` should let you import your dependencies.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure to use the latest Intellij Idea version. Current latest  version is 2018.1.4. You could use the [Jetbrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/) to update automatically.

Second, your `pom.xml` should be under `~/dev/micro-service` and not `~/dev/micro-service/src` - read [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) in order to understand how a maven project should look like.

Comment: My *pom.xml* is in the *~/dev/micro-service*

Comment: Sorry, It looks like it's under `~/dev/micro../src`. Did you try to update? What Maven version do you use?

Comment: I have solved it, because my POM file has some problems. If I change into other POM files, I can import the dependency automatically.